# Grok with Missing values using logstash

Tags: logstash, grok

I am trying to grok this inputs with logstash,

```
Nicolas Lauri 34 
Nicolas 33  #there is one space and it not works.
Nicolas  33 #there are two spaces and it works.
```

with this pattern

```
(%{WORD:firstname})? (%{WORD:lastname})? (%{NUMBER:age})?
```

Using the ()? I ignore missing values and say that are optionals, but the problem is we must put spaces between value to make it works.

i mean if i have this input:

```
Nicolas  19
```

i must put exactly two spaces between Nicolas et 19 to grok it correctly.

What should i do to avoid putting spaces ?

Answer (score 1):

Two choices:

1. Put the space in your optional pattern:  ( %{WORD})?
2. Allow one or more spaces between elements:  %{WORD} +%{WORD}

Comment: Not sure this helps since _all_ fields are optional (which might not make sense in the first place). With your first option there won't be a match if the firstname column is missing.

Comment: @MagnusBäck yes, you are right, it's just an example, in fact i have very 3 different lines in my log firewall file and I want:
to grok it and the result be stored into an elastic search cluster using the dedicated elastic search output.
what should i do :( ?

Comment: OP asked concrete question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623521/how-to-handle-multiple-inputs-with-logstash-in-the-same-file